# HTML table to excel using php, coming out as plain text?

Tags: php, html, header, http-headers, xlsx

I'm running an ajax call when i click a button.  The request hits this function and just prints out plain text.  I'm banging my head against the wall here.  what am i doing wrong?

```
    $test="<table border=1><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>";
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="BondTracker.xls"');
    echo $test;
```

i just get the string returning in my ajax call.  I'm running this off localhost

Comment: Ajax is a PITA for handling downloads, try doing it as a simple redirect: Note that you're not actually creating an Excel xls file, just a file that Excel can read, but which will give a warning message when opened in some versions of MS Excel

Comment: You cant set headers where the are already there, so redirect to a new page. :)

Comment: can i get an example in code?

Comment: nevermind.. i got this working.  basically dont use ajax. haha